# How to perform custom CRUD operations on an asp Gridview using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to perform custom CRUD operations on an asp Gridview using C#?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the onInsert, OnUpdating, OnDeleting events **I used a Datasource for the Populating the grid so that my fields are editable.

2.Row inserting

```
protected void grid1_RowInserting(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataInsertingEventArgs e)
        {   
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "spINSERTtblPARfinancialPropotions";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@financialPropotionsPercentageType", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = e.NewValues["financialPropotionsPercentageType"].ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@financialPropotionsPercentage", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(e.NewValues["financialPropotionsPercentage"]);
           cmd.Connection = con;

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    grid1.CancelEdit();
                }
             
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            finally
            {
                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();
            }

        }
```

3.Row Updating

```
protected void grid1_RowUpdating(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataUpdatingEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "spUPDATEtblPARfinancialPropotions";
            /// cmd.Parameters.Add("@TestConfigId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(e.NewValues["TestConfigId"]);
            //cmd.Parameters.Add("@ServiceId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(_serviceId);
            //cmd.Parameters.Add("@ParentTest", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ddlService.SelectedItem.Text.Trim();

            // cmd.Parameters.Add("@MainTest", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = e.NewValues["MainTest"].ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = e.OldValues["ID"];
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@financialPropotionsPercentageType", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = e.NewValues["financialPropotionsPercentageType"].ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@financialPropotionsPercentage", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(e.NewValues["financialPropotionsPercentage"]);
            cmd.Connection = con;

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    grid1.CancelEdit();
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            finally
            {
                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).